# Check for positive definiteness or positive semidefiniteness

Tags: python, math, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to check if a matrix is positive definite or positive semidefinite using Python.

How can I do that? Is there a dedicated function in SciPy for that or in other modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good solution is to calculate all the minors of determinants and check they are all non negatives.

Comment: Only the principal minors.

Comment: Isn´t this O(n!)? Cholesky factorization is faster

Answer (score 19):

I assume you already know your matrix is symmetric.

A good test for positive definiteness (actually the standard one !) is to try to compute its Cholesky factorization. It succeeds iff your matrix is positive definite.

This is the most direct way, since it needs O(n^3) operations (with a small constant), and you would need at least n matrix-vector multiplications to test "directly".

Comment: i was asking if there is a direct method for that. Thanks anyway

Comment: @sramij this is the most direct way to test

Comment: @sramij: This *is* a direct method, and is faster than anything else, unless you have additional *a priori* information about the matrix.

Comment: For the positive semi-definite case it remains true as [an abstract proposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices) that a real symmetric (or complex Hermitian) matrix is positive semi-definite if and only if a Cholesky factorization exists.  With a positive definite matrix the [usual algorithm](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.linalg.decomp.html#cholesky) succeeds because all the diagonal entries of L s.t. A =LL' are positive (a square root being taken).  If we hit a zero pivot, the computation halts, but the theory holds.

Comment: @hardmath: indeed, the existence of the cholesky decomposition for semidefinite matrices holds by a limiting argument.

Answer (score 14):

Cholesky decomposition is a good option if you're working with positive definite (PD) matrices.

However, it throws the following error on positive **semi**-definite (PSD) matrix, 
say,

```
A = np.zeros((3,3)) // the all-zero matrix is a PSD matrix
np.linalg.cholesky(A)
LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite -
Cholesky decomposition cannot be computed
```

For PSD matrices, you can use scipy/numpy's eigh() to check that all eigenvalues are non-negative.

```
>> E,V = scipy.linalg.eigh(np.zeros((3,3)))
>> E
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

However, you will most probably encounter numerical stability issues.
To overcome those, you can use the following function.

```
def isPSD(A, tol=1e-8):
  E = np.linalg.eigvalsh(A)
  return np.all(E > -tol)
```

Which returns `True` on matrices that are approximately PSD up to a given tolerance.

Comment: Actually, you can probably accelerate isPSD() by replacing eigh() with eigvalsh() which only computes the eigenvalues (I have not tested this).

Comment: I believe that `scipy.linalg.eigh(A)` should be altered to `np.linalg.eigh(A)`

Answer (score 6):

Check whether the whole eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix `A` are non-negative is time-consuming if `A` is very large, while the module `scipy.sparse.linalg.arpack` provides a good solution since one can customize the returned eigenvalues by specifying parameters.(see [`Scipy.sparse.linalg.arpack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh) for more information)

As we know if both ends of the spectrum of `A` are non-negative, then the rest eigenvalues must also be non-negative. So we can do like this:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import arpack
def isPSD(A, tol = 1e-8):
    vals, vecs = arpack.eigsh(A, k = 2, which = 'BE') # return the ends of spectrum of A
    return np.all(vals > -tol)
```

By this we only need to calculate two eigenvalues to check PSD, I think it's very useful for large `A`

Comment: Would it be ok with 'SA' and k=1?

Answer (score 0):

an easier method is to calculate the determinants of the minors for this matrx.

Comment: Computing the determinants requires `n` LU/QR/Cholesky decompositions, so just checking if Cholesky of the whole matrix succeeds should be faster.

Comment: It is true that a real symmetric (resp. complex Hermitian) matrix is positive semi-definite if and only if all its principal minors are nonnegative.  See [the note by John Prussing here](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/prussing/www/AIAA-Prussing_SemiDef.pdf) correcting the misstatement sometimes made that it suffices to check the leading principal minors are nonnegative.  The latter is necessary but not sufficient for positive semi-definiteness.