# Performing simple inverse and multiplication operations on Mat matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

I have detected a number of points from 2 images. I am trying to find a transformation matrix between these 2 images. So I need to do an inverse of the matrix coordinates of one matrix and then multiply it to the coordinates of the other Mat matrix. I used very simple opencv methods but I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqp7v.jpg. I do not understand why. Here is my code http://pastebin.com/Tef42E2Q. Can anybody guide me here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should  make sure at least two things before Mat inverse.

1. The Matrix should be square.
2. The Matrix should be non-singular, that is determinant should be non-zero.

**Eg:**

```
    Mat A(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    A=(Mat_<float>(3,3)<< 0,2,3,\
                          4,5,6,\
                          7,8,9);
    cout<<A <<endl;

    if(determinant(A)!=0){
    Mat B=A.inv();
    cout<<B <<endl;
    }
```

Also see the answer [Mat.inv() yielding all zeroes in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051669/mat-inv-yielding-all-zeroes-in-opencv)

**Edit:-**

Here is some bug I found in your code

The piece of code

```
    Mat matrix_f(2,3,CV_32F);
    matrix_f=Mat(coordinates_f);
```

should changed to

```
    Mat matrix_f(2,3,CV_32F);
    matrix_f=Mat(coordinates_f);
    matrix_f=matrix_f.reshape(1,2);
```

because later you are going to multiply with a 3X3 Mat, So we will make it's rows to 3

And next is change the lines

```
    Mat new_left(3,3,CV_32F);
    new_left=Mat(coordinates_l_new);
```

to

```
      Mat new_left(3,3,CV_32F);
      new_left=Mat(coordinates_l_new);
      new_left=new_left.reshape(1,3);
```

as you are going to find the inverse of new_left, it should be square matrix.

And finally make sure the Mat is non-singular by finding determinant

```
 if(determinant(new_left)!=0) {
        Mat T(3,3,CV_32F);
        T=matrix_f * (new_left.inv());
  }
```

Comment: your piece of code works perfectly if I manually input the elements of matrix A. But my problem is when I take a matrix found earlier in the code,I am not able to find its inverse and nor am I able to perform a multiplication with it, giving me the error above

Comment: Can you show your full code?...In the link you provided with your question   you may use the code `Mat T=matrix_f * (new_left.inv());` see if it working.

Comment: If you post your image it will help me debug your code

Comment: okayy thanks!one more thing..when I apply this transformation matrix to the original left image and when I try to display it,it shows a yellow image with the detected green pixels. I added this part inside the if statement: Mat left_transformed=Mat::zeros(left.size(),left.type());
  left_transformed=left.mul(T);
  imshow("left_trans",left_transformed);Why does it not display the transformed left image correctly?

Comment: For Mat::mul both  Mat should be same type and size [See OpenCV Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mul)

Comment: okayy!!I was trying to apply the transformation matrix to the whole image so that it becomes like that http://i.imgur.com/DXxKu5V.jpg. But after looking at opencv doc,this is not possible. Do you have any suggestions?because I tried affineTransform as well,it did not work :s

Comment: You can apply affinTransfor with your own Mat like `Mat warp_dst = Mat::zeros( front.rows, front.cols, front.type() ); warpAffine( front, warp_dst, T, warp_dst.size() ); imshow("warp_dst",warp_dst);`

Comment: that's exactly what I did but I get this error message http://i.imgur.com/DXxKu5V.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46816/discussion-between-haris-and-steph)