# Testing if an operation has been performed correctly in python 3 numpy?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to calculate a Hessian (matrix of second derivatives), and modify it iff it is not positive definite. Cholesky decomposition fails if a matrix is not symmetric positive (semi)definite, and Hessians are symmetric. Therefore I can use `numpy.linalg.cholesky` on my matrix, and this seems to be one of the most efficient ways of checking. See [this post for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563743/check-for-positive-definiteness-or-positive-semidefiniteness/5565951#5565951).

Now I am not sure how to condition on the Cholesky decomposition being performed without error. For instance

```
H=hessian(X)

if np.linalg.cholesky(H) ...??? :
      'modification'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html). The function `np.linalg.cholesky` raises an `LinAlgError` if the decomposition fails. Hence, wrapping it up in a `try`/`except` block would be a possible solution.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5))

# compute hessian of X
# H = hessian(X)

try:
    L = np.linalg.cholesky(H)
except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
    # modifications
```